# Populate a table with the filename of an attachment

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a basic records database of paid invoices. On our network drive, we have a single PDF file labeled with a 3-letter code property code, MMDDYY date, and vendor name. After the PDF is save to the network drive, the same information is inputted into the Access Database, (3-letter property code, date, vendor name). Is there a way, via VBA, to populate those fields by attaching the file to the record?

I get about 40-60 files per week, and I can perform this action by exporting a .txt file of all filenames in the folder, then prep that text file for import into Access...but I found that it is faster to just input each record by hand.

Not everyone has access to the network drive (files contain financial data), but some need access to identify when an invoice was paid.

Comment: See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb258184(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Travis,

What you can do is to have some VBA code that loops the folder, checks for new PDF files, and then adds these to the table. Something like this seems to work:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFile As String
Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblFileData WHERE 1=2;")
strFolder = "J:\test-data\"
strFile = Dir(strFolder, vbNormal)
Do
    If Right(strFile, 3) = "pdf" Then
        If IsNull(DLookup("PropertyCode", "tblFileData", "PropertyCode & ProcessDate & VendorName='" & Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4) & "'")) Then
            With rsData
                .AddNew
                !PropertyCode = Left(strFile, 3)
                !ProcessDate = Mid(strFile, 4, 6)
                !VendorName = Mid(strFile, 10, Len(strFile) - 13)
                .Update
            End With
        End If
    End If
    strFile = Dir
Loop Until strFile = ""
```

You may want to also consider storing the file name in this table so that users can open this file on the network, and also moving processed files to a new folder so that you are only working on new files each day.

Regards